# Probability roots of quadratic equation is real when determined by three die rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

So I understand that one approach to solving this question is to simply list out all possible values of a,b,c such that the roots of the quadratic equation are not real. And then divide this number by the total number of possible outcomes from rolling die three times.

However I got lazy and wanted to do less listing, so I tried to come up with a short cut. For example, you could roll a die three times and get (1,4,2) or (2,4,1) for (a,b,c). Both are acceptable for maintaining the condition that the roots of the quadratic equation be real.

So instead of counting both, I would only count (1,4,2) and not list (2,4,1). My total count came to be 25 combos of die rolls which would keep a,b,c real.

Then, instead of dividing by 6 x 6 x 6, I decided that since for my numerator I didn't care about the order of the values for a and c, I would disregard order for the first two die rolls. I.e I would not count a roll of (1,2) as separate from (2,1).

However, it's possible that the same number can be rolled twice. This could happen 6 times.

So the way that I calculated my probability was like so:

$\frac{25}{\frac{(6x6)-6}{2!} * 6}$ = $\frac{25}{126}$

The final result however, does not match the solution which is $\frac{43}{216}$ which notably is fraction that cannot be simplified further.

What's wrong with my logic/reasoning behind the shortcut I took?

Comment: For the roots to be real, $b^2-4ac\geq0$. So, for each $(a,c)$, compute $2\sqrt{ac}$. All $b\geq$ this square root corresponds to a quadratic with real roots

Comment: @Shisui Did you count $(a,b,a)$? These should be included in the denominator too.

Comment: Is the die the normal 6 sided die?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that different combinations can occur in different numbers of ways; e.g. $(1,1,1)$ can occur in $1$ way and $(1,2,3)$ can occur in $6$ ways. You can’t correct for the fact that you didn’t include these factors in the numerator by a global factor in the denominator; you need to include this factor for each of the $25$ combinations that you found, and then divide by $6^3$.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on why you can't correct for omission of different orderings of the first and second value (for a and c respectively) in the numerator by using a global factor in denominator?

Comment: @Shisui: The correct value is of the form $(1x_1+2x_2)/6^3$, where $x_1$ is the number of combinations that you counted with $a=c$ and $x_2$ is the number of combinations that you counted with $a\ne c$. If you instead form $x_1+x_2=25$ by just counting all those combinations together, you can't apply a single factor to correct this sum, because it includes a part that should have been multiplied by $1$ and a part that should have been multiplied by $2$. (Of course there's a factor that you can multiply it to get the right result, but to find it you'd need to know the right result.)